# Difference between two dates in dates using Google bigquery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, datediff, date-difference

How can I get the difference in days between 2 timestamp fields in Google Big Query?

The only function I know is `Datediff` which only works in Legacy SQL but I'm in Standard SQL.

For example: the difference between 20180115 to 20180220 is 36 days.

Comment: It's only in part because of Jan 31. It's also because of Feb 4. Anyway, isn't the function DATEDIF?

Comment: No, this function doesn't work on standard sql.

Comment: How about `EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE '20180220' - DATE '20180115')` - I'm just guessing here.

Comment: No, because if they are in different months it will be wrong.

Comment: I guess I don't really know what 'standard' sql is.

Answer (score 53):

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_diff), you should use `DATE_DIFF` function in standard SQL.

Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(DATE '2018-02-20', DATE '2018-01-15', DAY) as days_diff;
```

result:

```
Row days_diff    
 1     36
```

Answer (score 4):

First you need to "translate" you string representation of date into date type using [`PARSE_DATE()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#parse_date) function and then [`DATE_DIFF()`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_diff) function allows you to calculate difference/distance between two dates as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DATE_DIFF(
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '20180220'), 
    PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', '20180115'), 
    DAY
  ) days
```

produces:

```
Row days     
1   36
```